# which one is good practise: Executing custom SQL directly or ORM in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am learning Django and new to it. So which is best way to get database out, through `Manager.raw()` or through Django ORM. I know SQL to some extend.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using SQL instead of ORM?

Comment: Why would you think the developers of Django would go to such lengths to build the ORM, if they didn't want you to use it?

Answer (score 3):

As @Selcuk quoted:

> When the model query APIs don’t go far enough, you can fall back to writing raw SQL.

Which means that you should be using the ORM unless you absolutely have to fall back. Truly, you can go quite far with just the ORM.

Some quick, basic advantages;

- It results in cleaner code.
- When working with objects you get the advantages of object methods, and methods that you build.
- Easier fetching of relative objects.

As an example, let's say you have `users` and `comments`

It might look like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField()


class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Let's grab that last user that signed up:

`user = User.objects.last()`

Wow, that was easy. Now let's get all of their comments:

```
user.comment_set.all()
```

Seriously, do you still want to write SQL?

Let's grab all of our new comments since yesterday:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(created_at__gte='2016-04-18')
```

Oh, wait, you wanted the comments since yesterday of a specific email address? Well, the model object manager returns a queryset, we can chain these guys along all day long, and it won't get evaluated (actually hit the database) until we try to do anything with it. They're *lazily evaluated*

```
user_comments = comments.filter(author__email='shankar@stackoverflow.com')
```

That dunder (double underscore) can mean a few things. In this case, we're filtering on the `Comment` model's `author` field, which is a foreign key relationship with the `User` model and dunder allows us to specify a field on it for comparisons.

Above, the dunder was used to specify an comparison operator, `__gte`, which is "greater than or equal to"

Hopefully you're starting to see why the ORM is useful, and these are just scratching the surface and handling selecting objects!

Answer (score 0):

ORM when possible, SQL when not. From [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries):

> When the model query APIs don’t go far enough, you can fall back to writing raw SQL.